# Forcing a callback to be executed first

Tags: python, python-2.7, callback

I've got the following codesnippet in a program using secure multiparty computation:

```
c = self.runtime.open(b)  # open result
c.addCallback(self.determine) 

j = self.compute(i)
return j
```

Now the function `determine` sets a boolean to either false or true, depending on the value of c. This boolean is then used by the function `compute`.

I thought that callbacks are always executed first, before the rest of the program is. However, I'm getting an error from `compute` that the boolean is undefined.

How can I force the callback to be executed **before** `compute` is executed?

Because I'm working within a secure multiparty computation framework, I have to work with callbacks since the value for `c` is a shared secret. However, the problem would also appear without secret shares I think. The language is Python.

The code for `determine` and `compute` would be something like this:

```
def determine(c):
    global computeB
    computeB = False
    if c == 1:
        computeB = True
    else:
        computeB = False
    return c

def compute(i):
    if computeB:
         do this
    else:
         do this
    return result
```

Comment: you need to call compute from determine, that's how callbacks work.

Comment: What is executing your callbacks then? Clearly your callback is not yet executed by the time you call `compute()`.. Without more details on the framework you are using here it is *impossible* to help you any further with that.

Comment: And the expression `c == 1` returns a boolean; just use `computeB = c == 1` instead of `if` - `else` statements.

Answer (score 0):

The callback gets executed when it gets executed. There is no point in "making" it execute earlier.

I guess you are dealing with twisted so heres a tutorial http://krondo.com/?page_id=1327 but it is helpfull even for understanding async programming in general, which you obviously need.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a pro in async but I think you want to yield your first function and tell your routine to wait before it goes on.

```
yield self.runtime.open(b)  # open result

j = self.compute(i)
return j
```